# SharePoint Online (Office 365) Workflow to Copy New File Versions to Record Center Automatically

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-online, office-365, rest, csom

We have a design goal to copy every new version of files in our Office 365 / SharePoint Online-based Document Center site to a separate Records Center site automatically using a SharePoint 2013 workflow.  I am looking for advice on the best method to accomplish this.

Our current thinking is:

(1) When files are added or updated in Doc Center, fire a workflow that sends the relevant file information to a remote web service using the "`Call a Web Service`" workflow action.

(2) The receiving web service sits in Azure, and will put the information about the file on a message queue in Azure.

(3) A "`service app`" running on an Azure Worker Role will process the items on the queue.  That process will likely involve CSOM code to interact with the two SharePoint sites to capture the source file's metadata and transfer the file/metadata to the Dropoff Library in the Records Center site.

One important requirement is that we have the ability to manipulate some of the metadata fields prior to copying each file to the Records Center.

My questions are:

- Is this a reasonable approach, or is there a simpler method?
- If our Office 365 authentication uses ADFS, what is the best way for the "service app" to authenticate to each of the two SharePoint sites?  (Concerned here about authentication redirection.)
- Should the "`service app`" use the SharePoint RESTFUL api instead of CSOM?

Comment: Regarding Azure Worker Role Authentication:  Haven't tried it yet, but this looks like a good possibility for registering my unattended external Azure "service app" with SharePoint Online and storing credentials in the app for oAuth access to SPO:  http://blog.symprogress.com/2013/11/call-sharepoint-online-csom-from-an-external-application/.